# Access Play Framework Router routing table at run time

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I am writing an `EssentialFilter` so I can perform an operation on every request. However all that the filter receives is a `RequestHeader` object and I need to know information about the actual controller that will be handling this request later down the line.

This information is plain and clear in `routes.conf`:

```
GET  /foobar   controllers.MyController.foobar()
GET  /bashbaz   controllers.MyController.bashbaz()
```

And I can even see that in my `target` folder a generated routing table is laid out very neatly in a `documentation` object:

```
// This example greatly simplified for clarity
class Routes() {
  def documentation = List(
    ("""GET""", prefix + """foobar""", """controllers.MyController.foobar()"""),
    ("""GET""", prefix + """bashbaz""", """controllers.MyController.bashbaz()""")
}
```

My only question is: *how do I access this during runtime*?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483556/446554) coincidentally shows that the routes *used* to be available via `Play.maybeApplication.get.routes` but that is now deprecated. How do I get a `Routes` object at run time?

Answer (score 1):

Play actually makes `Routes` available via dependency injection (DI) of its `Router` object. If you already have DI set up in your app then you only need to inject it into your constructor:

```
import play.api.routing.Router

class YourFilter(router: Router) extends EssentialFilter { ... }
```

If you haven't set DI up yet then I recommend reading [the official reference](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) on the subject. [This third-party blog post](https://www.schibsted.pl/blog/dependency-injection-play-framework-scala/) also details some modern libraries that can be useful.

However, if you want to see what controller handles a particular `RequestHeader`, then I recommend ignoring the `Router` and `documentation` objects entirely and make use of the convenient `handlerDef` implicit:

```
import play.api.routing.Router.RequestImplicits.WithHandlerDef

override def apply(next: EssentialAction) = { request: RequestHeader =>
  val handlerDefOpt = request.handlerDef
  handlerDefOpt.map(handlerDef =>
    // Would be "controllers.MyController" in your example
    handlerDef.controller

    // Would be "foobar" or "bashbaz" in your example
    handlerDef.method

    // Would be "GET" in your example
    handlerDef.verb

    // Would be "/foobar" or "/bashbaz" in your example
    handlerDef.path

  )
}
```

Or you can also get the `HandlerDef` from within the request's `attrs`:

```
val handlerDef: Option[HandlerDef] = request.attrs.get(Router.Attrs.HandlerDef)
```